# Making parameter of main method as final

Tags: java, methods, arguments, program-entry-point

i saw a different signature of main() i.e.

```
public class Demo {

    public static final void main(final String[] args) {

        .............
        .............

    }

}
```

What is the benefit to make main()'s argument as final. please explain!

Comment: you also can do `public static void main(String[] a)` :O

Comment: I don't get what is being asked

Comment: Why? Why not? Where does it say it won't work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Method parameters in Java are local variables.  Declaring them as final allows you to access them from inner anonymous classes.  Other than that, it can help prevent potential bugs that happen when you change parameter values.

So in your example code, using `final String[] args` will work just fine.

Answer (score 4):

String[] args is just a variable declaration, it corresponds to the command line parameters, so it can be final.